# How to update OpenSSL in Android Vitamio Library

Tags: android, openssl, vitamio

I am using [Vitamio Bundle](https://vitamio.org/) for streaming in my application 
Yesterday I saw this email that google sent to me 
Please tell me how should I update openSSL in vitamio library ?

> This information is intended for developers of apps statically linking
>   against a version of OpenSSL that precedes 1.02f/1.01r.  These
>   versions contain security vulnerabilities.
>
> Please migrate your app(s) to OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r or higher as soon as
>   possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
>   Beginning July 11, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new
>   apps or updates that use older versions of OpenSSL.

How I can update OpenSSL in my Vitamio library?

Thanks in advance.